# Can Hive periodically append or insert incremental data to the same table file in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, spark-streaming

I'm loading network captured data every minute from Spark streaming (from Flume exec), then aggregate data according to ip address, save to Hive at the end. To make it faster I create Hive ORC table with partition on ip address, it works well. The only issue is every minute it creates many (depends on how many ip addresses) kb small files, now I use "ALTER TABLE...CONCATENATE;" to merge them manually, but I think it could be easier, so want to ask whether there is solution that can incrementally merge/append new data to first minute table files instead of creating new table files every minute. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I give up, looks no direct solution as Hive can't append content to existing datafile for performance consideration. Now my alternative is still to concatenate it every week, the problem is query will be broken with error message (complaining it can't find data file) when it's doing concatenation, so there is big business impact. Now I'm thinking replacing Hive with HBase or Kudu which is more flexible and can provide update/delete operation.